# How to properly set up a gradient for canvas?

Tags: canvas

I'm doing color selection using canvas, and I'm running into the problem that I can't get the fff color at the top left point. I described my config in the demo.
https://codepen.io/Ivancoppen/pen/WNLXrpy?editors=1010

```
I tried building a demo to demonstrate the problem.
```

Comment: Traces `255,255,255,255` (fully opaque white) - isn't that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, all correct, but in the demo I showed that at coordinates (0 0) I get not full white, but 254 254 254 255

Comment: The problem is in line 22 of the code, there the getImageData method returns me not full white